# Como edito o scroll bar de uma tag select?

Tags: html, css, html-select

```
<select id="select">
  <option value="week"> Previsão Semanal</option>
  <option value="daily"> Previsão Diária</option>
</select>
```

Eu tenho este código aqui e em css queria editar o scroll do select colocando-lhe a letra de outra cor e que o background não seja o branco

Comment: <select id="select">
                    <option value="week"> Previsão Semanal</option>
                    <option value="daily"> Previsão Diária</option>
                </select>

Comment: Você quer editar o scrollbar ou o "popup" gerado quando clica no select, que mostra as opções/option?

Answer (score 0):

Muito simples... Basta utilizar os atributos backgroud e color do elemento. Nesse caso ficaria assim:

```
    #select{
      background: red;
      color:#fff;
    }
```

Comment: Não resulta essa solução! Isso faz com que o próprio select mude não quando eu clico no select e aparece todas as opções! E é isso que eu quero.. É tirar aquele branco de fundo quando aparecem todas as opções